# Craft user group permissions

Tags: users, user-groups

I have a group of different regions which would like to have region admins who can't approve content from each other's region but also have a super admin who can approve content from any regions. I will outline below the how this is laid out and would like to know if its possible with Craft.

- **Super Admin** (master admin - approval master)

  - **Region 1** (region admin - approvers)

    - Location 1 (location admin - drafters)
    - Location 2 (location admin - drafters)
    - Location 3 (location admin - drafters)
  - **Region 2** (region admin - approvers)

    - Location 4 (location admin - drafters)
    - Location 5 (location admin - drafters)
  - **Region 3** (region admin - approvers)

    - Location 6 (location admin - drafters)

**Super Admin** can approve any item created by location admins and region admins.

**Region Admins** can approve only content created by location admins within their region only

**Location Admins** can only create drafts

Comment: Are "regions" limited to specific sections in Craft?

Comment: This will be using Locales so we would want the Locales to be managed by a Region admin.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something.

- Create the 6 locales; one for each location (settings > locales)
- Create user groups (10) and set permissions (settings > users)

  - Allow location drafters to only 'edit' and 'create', but not 'publish' (for each section)
  - Restrict location drafters to their respective locale (single locale)
  - Allow Region Admins to edit, create, and publish (for each section)
  - Restrict Region Admins to their region locales (more than one locale)
  - Allow Super Admins to edit, create, and publish (for each section)
  - Allow Super Admins for all locales

This is assuming of course you have a locale for each location (and not for each region).